# How Do You Add Mods to your Minecraft on Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft

I've been trying to add mods to my minecraft using the old way of putting them in the bin folder.  However, I do not have a bin folder in my .minecraft folder.  How do I get the bin folder or find a different way to add the mods.  I have already tried using the magic launcher and it did not work.  I also so tried Ctrl-h to show the hidden items and the bin folder still did not show up. All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try creating the directory yourself?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: mkdir path/to/.minecraft/bin

Comment: I get this message when I type that:           cannot create directory ‘path/to/.minecraft/bin’: No such file or directory

Comment: "/path/to/.minecraft/bin" should be replaced with the path to the .minecraft folder on your computer. It's probably /home/[username]/.minecraft/bin . So for example, since my username is 'timothy' I would type     "mkdir /home/timothy/.minecraft/bin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not ubuntu native, but I did this on FEDORA 20, should work for all linux:

1. Download MINECRAFT FORGE UNIVERSAL INSTALLER (.jar) for the version you want (1.7.2 etc.) and run it using `java`.
2. There should now be a `mods` folder in your `.minecraft` directory. If it isn't there, just make a new folder and call it `mods`
3. Put your mods in that folder and run minecraft. There should now be a new profile called forge. Press play and you're done!